# C++ include libary OSX, clang, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, cmake, macos-high-sierra

i'm trying to develop a small scaled application to exchange data between a pc and a plc using the snap7 Libary.

I installed snap7 via brew and edited my cmake with the following lines

```
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/snap7/1.4.2_1/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/snap7/1.4.2_1/lib)
```

so far so good i can now do this

```
#include <snap7.h>
```

but when i try to build the application (using CLion on macOS 10.13.3 with XCode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

i get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TS7Client::TS7Client()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Zebra_TCP] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Zebra_TCP.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Is the `snap7`-library compiled for 64 bit architecture?

Comment: via brew i only get the libsnap7.dylib / snap7.h files directly in /usr/local/cellar. however if you download the source directly there is the option to recompile the libary for every given architecture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Comment: In short: neither `include_directories` nor `link_directories` command **links** to the library. You need to use `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: edited my cmake like this:
FIND_LIBRARY(LIB snap7)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT} "${LIB}")

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT} PUBLIC /usr/local/Cellar/snap7/1.4.2_1/include) but still getting the same error